# Using an Array in another method

Tags: java, arrays

I am reading in some data from a file and storing it an array. I was wondering if it is possible to access the array that is storing the data from the file in other methods?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Cards {
    private static final String Cards_CARDS_DATA_FILE = "./cards.txt";
    public char[] cardStore;

    public void loadCards() throws IOException {


        FileReader readingFile = new FileReader(Cards_CARDS_DATA_FILE);
        BufferedReader File = new BufferedReader(readingFile);
        for (String line; (line = File.readLine()) != null;) {



//copying the stuff in cards.txt to an array. Printed out just to check it actually works.
            cardStore = line.toCharArray();
            System.out.println(cardStore);

        }

        File.close();

    }

    public void tester() throws IOException {

        System.out.println(cardStore);

    }
}
```

Comment: `this.cardStore`? What's the problem with `System.out.println(cardStore)`?

Comment: Sure it's possible, it's easier to try than posting question here

Comment: when your input file has multiple lines in it, your array will only contain the last line

Answer (score 2):

You can access and print the instance field from any instance-scoped context of your class.

Now, to print its populated contents, you'd have to populate it first, which is done in `loadCards()` (hence the method would require to be invoked successfully - i.e. in terms of I/O as well).

As long as `loadCards()` has been invoked successfully (i.e. file operation and array population succeeded), `tester()` should have no issue printing actual contents of `cardStore` reflecting the file contents.

A word of caution, you want to use `Arrays.toString` to print a human-readable representation of your array.

Comment: Sorry, you're wrong. You can access `cardStore` in any instance method even if `loadCards()` has not been called.

Comment: Still, you can print `cardStore` without having called `loadCards()`.

Comment: Yes, I think the broader picture here is OP wants to know if they're printing **something**, not `null`.

Comment: I know, but my point is that you can make your answer much clearer.

Comment: @m0skit0 fair enough. Full rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
A class instance variable will always be accessable for methods inside the same class.

**Some extra info**

```
public class Cards {
    private static final String Cards_CARDS_DATA_FILE = "./cards.txt";
    private char[] cardStore;
public void loadCards() throws IOException {
    FileReader readingFile = new FileReader(Cards_CARDS_DATA_FILE);
    BufferedReader File = new BufferedReader(readingFile);
    for (String line; (line = File.readLine()) != null;) {

        cardStore = line.toCharArray();
        System.out.println(cardStore);
    }
    File.close();
}

public char[] getCardStore(){
   return this.cardstore;
}

public void setCardStore(char[] cardstore){
   this.cardstore = cardStore;
}
```

}

This way you have the right encapsulation. (public variables aint prefered)
You can now access the cardstore also outside this class.

**Addition**:

```
public void tester() throws IOException {

        System.out.println(cardStore);

    }
```

could/should be more something like this:

```
public void tester() throws IOException {
    for(char card:cardStore){
        System.out.println("test info: " + card);
    }
}
```

In the first way you will print the hashcode of the char[] object, not the data stored inside. If your intentions are to print data. If you only want to see if it is filled or not it can be done easier.

```
public void tester() throws IOException {
    if(cardStore != null && cardStore.length > 0){
        System.out.println("test info: cardStore has " + cardStore.length + " rows.");
    }
}
```